# Waiting for N Events in Kafka: How does the Group-Count-Filter Approach work?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, message-queue, apache-kafka-streams, distributed-computing

#### Background

In the book [Designing Event-Driven Systems](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/designing-event-driven-systems/9781492038252/), the author highlighted a common use case in business systems where there is a need to wait or *N* events to occur.

The example given is of an orders service that needs to wait for three separate validation services, all sent via the same topic, to return a `PASS`. (*I interpret this to mean that there will be three validation messages on the same topic with the same key, each with a value indicating success or failure*.)

The author stated that the solution will take the following form (assuming that the counting is based on the key):

1. Group by the key.
2. Count occurrences of each key (using an aggregator executed with a window).
3. Filter the output for the required count.

#### Question

How exactly does each of the step above works, and what are the classes / methods involved?

- In particular, does the first step (grouping by the key) refers to using the [KStream::groupByKey](https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KStream.html#groupByKey--) method?
- If so, the output will be a [KGroupedStream](https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KGroupedStream.html), and step two presumably uses one of the [Count](https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KGroupedStream.html#count--) methods and returns a [KTable](https://kafka.apache.org/25/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/streams/kstream/KTable.html).
- However, having a KTable, *how do we filter the output on a KTable*, as per step three?

Answer (score 0):

I guess your assumptions are right. For step (2) it depends, but if you assume that all the messages you are waiting for have the same key and you are only interested if three messages with the same key got received, calling `count()` is what you want.

As a next step (ie, (3)), you would call `KTable#filter()` to get all rows with a count of 3.

Finally, you can call `toStream()` and this stream should contain a record each time one key reaches the count of 3.

(As a side remarks: all entries would stay in the `KTable` forever by default, thus you also need to take care to delete entries that did reach count of 3 at some point.)